# How to watch changes in angular2?

Tags: angular

I want to set an attribute which changes on some event:

```
<div [style.left]="posLeft"></div>
```

and the event:

```
onMouseMove(event) {
   this.posLeft = event.clientX;
}
```

The MouseMove event is fired but [style.left] isn't updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that style.left expects something like "23px" and not just a number.

```
[style.left]="getPos()"
```

and js:

```
getPos() {
   return this.posLeft + "px";
}
```

Comment: even better: `[style.left.px]="posLeft"`